# Blender model is too heavy

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, gltf

My question is pretty simple, I load 4 models and some texture for my threeJS website but the first loading is too long. You can take a look : https://issammerikhi.vercel.app/

Do you know a simple and efficient way to reduce my model size ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: reduce the complexity of the models, ie. reduce the number of verticies.

Comment: the bulk of your file size seems to be textures, so try to reduce their size?

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on file compression?

[image: File Compression]

That should help reduce your file size~

Comment: The checkbox shown here is for the Blender project itself, but it doesn't affect glTF exports for ThreeJS.  There's a different compression checkbox on the glTF export dialog options that might help reduce the export size.  But in general, reducing the number of polygons or size/number of texturemaps can help the most.